# Call stored procedure using ODBC from PHP running on Linux - odbc_prepare not working

Tags: sql-server, linux, odbc

I need to call a stored procedure in SQL Server. 
I am using ODBC via PHP on Linux.

I can connect, but cannot call the procedure, something is not quite right with my syntax.

If the developer of the database I'm calling were to run it himself (on Windows), he would write it as 
**exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb 158**
(158 is the parameter I need to pass)

---

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:MSSQLServer", $username, $password);  // this works fine

$stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn, "call DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb(?)");     // THIS DOES NOT

if(!$stmt) {echo "could not prepare statement.";}

$success = odbc_execute($stmt, 158);

odbc_close($conn);
```

---

I have already tried these different ways (one at at time of course):

---

```
  $stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn, 'call DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb(?)');
  $stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn, "call DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb(?)");
  $stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn, "call dbo.DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb(?)");    
  $stmt    = odbc_prepare($conn, "call exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb(?)");
```

---

Thank you for the suggestions. I have now tried all of these, to no avail:

---

```
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb ?");
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "call DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb ?");
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "call exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb ?");
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "{call DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb ?}");
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "{exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb ?}"); 
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "{exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb (?)}"); 
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "{exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb 158}");
$stmt = odbc_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM MyTableName");
```

---

I am using **PDO ODBC** for my connection so I think I need to write it like this instead?? These lines do not fail until the execute line.

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:MSSQLServer", $username, $password);
//$stmt = $conn->prepare("exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb ?");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb (?)");
//$stmt->bind_param("158");  
$stmt->bind_param(158);  
$stmt->execute();

$conn = new PDO("odbc:MSSQLServer", $username, $password);
    if ($conn) { 
       echo "connected. ";
    } else {
       echo "not connected. ";
    }
```

Comment: I also reviewed this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-how-to/running-stored-procedures-call-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-ver15 which says that in order to run a procedure as an RPC, I should construct a SQL statement that uses the ODBC CALL escape sequence. Which I am trying to do but I must not have it quite right yet. Maybe I need to include those curly braces?

Comment: I just noticed you’re on Linux.  What ODBC driver are you using?  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Maybe this is because I am connecting with PDO_ODBC driver. My connection is made by $conn = new PDO("odbc:MSSQLServer", $username, $password); not by odbc_connect.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php

Comment: Also could be a limitation of the ODBC driver you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found code that would work, it is for **PDO_ODBC**, using PHP 7.  I never could bind the parameter, so I just built the entire SQL code as a variable.

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:MSSQLServer", $username, $password);
$TheMSSQL = "exec DW_Insert_MemberFromWeb " . $myvar;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($TheMSSQL);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt) { 
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $rst)
    {
        $MemberNum = $rst[MyFieldName];
        //do some other stuff
    }
}
```